# Problems using awful.util.spawn in Awesome WM

Tags: linux, keymap, awesome-wm

I am having trouble using the awful.util.spawn call in my rc.lua config file for Awesome WM.

If I use: `awful.util.spawn("xclock")` it works.

But if I try `awful.util.spawn("setxkbmap fr")` there is no effect.

Specifically, I'd like to change the keyboard map to AZERTY.

I've tried using `setxkbmaps` by calling a file but it makes no difference. If I open a terminal after Awesome loads, the command works. 
I've also tried creating (I didn't have one before, nor in my `/etc/skel/` folder) a `.xinitrc` file containing `setxkbmap fr`, but it doesn't work either...

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 i686 with the latest AWM I think.

EDIT: I use the `lightdm` login which automatically detects my keyboard layout!
EDIT: uing `awful.util.spawn_with_shell` seems to fix the problem...

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that a solution is to use the `awful.util.spawn_with_shell` call instead of simply the `awful.util.spawn`.

I also eliminated the .xinitrc file in order to be sure that this works.